# What do the expressions "offshore", "blind filing" and "operating at a total loss" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, metaphors, finance, cinema

In the 2014 film *The Other Woman*, there is an exchange between several characters:

> **Carmela** - Yay.- Mark's not just a cheating scumbag, he's also a thief. Look what I found. This is a list of all of the start-up companies that Mark has invested in. Three are offshore, but only one was a blind filing. No board of directors. It has a P.O. box
>   for an address, and it's been operating at a total loss in the Bahamas. ServiceCircuit.

So what did Carmela mean by : *"Three are offshore, but only one was a blind filing.
No board of directors. It's been operating at a total loss in the Bahamas"*?

**Please note**: English is not my native language, so the simpler and clearer you can make your explanation, the better.

Comment: "Scumbag", although commonly used, is a crude term that many people will find offensive. It means a used condom.

Answer (score 2):

An "offshore" company is one which is created under the authority of a foreign government, typically in order to realize tax advantages or to pursue activities which are hampered or prohibited under US law.

*Operating at a total loss* means that the business has no revenue at all, only expenses—suggesting that is not a legitimate business but a device for disguising money gained from some illicit activity as bookkeeping losses in order to move it into a bank or into investments where the authorities cannot recognize or seize it.

*Filing* here refers to the process by which a legal corporation is created, by *filing* the articles of incorporation with the appropriate state authority. This particular corporation is *blind* in the sense that its owners cannot be identified: it has no named board of directors and only a postoffice box for an address.

ServiceCircuit thus provides Mark a double layer of protection for his crooked activities: the company is beyond the reach of US or state oversight, and Mark's own involvement is completely anonymous.

Comment: I hope you're one of the people working _against_ people like Mark.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm a writer: I have no revenue to hide.

Comment: Ah: hence the user-name.